# Increasing Virtual Disk in VMWare doesn't show new space is Available in LVM

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, lvm, partition

I have inctreased the size of my virtual HD from 79GB to 100GB on VMWare ESXi 4.1 Virtual Machine

http://screencast.com/t/j6Y2SmLES3P7

after that I have restarted VM but when I go to VM

```
[root@linxuph53]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_linuxph53
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               79.50 GiB
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              2544
  Alloc PE / Size       2544 / 79.50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               Y269kC-3Jzh-hSHz-Jgwv-lkVO-K69T-mzrqaZ
```

I don't see that I got new UNALLOCATED space, so technically I can't expand my /home partition

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg_linuxph53/lv_home
  VG Name                vg_linuxph53
  LV UUID                bWrIb2-ek2G-2G3Y-a6kA-8nnB-8fM4-6OenbJ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                35.16 GiB
  Current LE             1125
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

any ideas?

after I rebooted VM and running fdisk -l

that's what I see

```
  [root@linxuph53 semenov]# fdisk -l

  Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00074e78

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
  /dev/sda2         1026048   167772159    83373056   8e  Linux LVM

  Disk /dev/dm-0: 41.3 GB, 41305505792 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5021 cylinders, total 80674816 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

  Disk /dev/dm-1: 6308 MB, 6308233216 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 766 cylinders, total 12320768 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Disk /dev/dm-1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

  Disk /dev/dm-2: 37.7 GB, 37748736000 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4589 cylinders, total 73728000 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Disk /dev/dm-2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need a reboot of the VM to reread the partition table. You could try the `partprobe` command to see if that reflects a change in `fdisk -l` output, but a reboot should definitely fix it.

Comment: I did it, that's what it says now - pls see my updated post

Comment: So did that work?